# NSolve and FindRoot give a value which is not correct; how can I obtain the exact solution of the given equation?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I have two functions $ f(x,y) $ and $ g(x,y) $, I use this code

```
f[x_, y_] :=  Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];
g[x_, y_] := (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

p1=ContourPlot[  g[x, y] == 0 , {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, Pi}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 10,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},   f[x, y] > 1]]

p2=ContourPlot[  g[x, y] == 0 , {x, 1.56, 1.58}, {y, 3.1, Pi}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},   f[x, y] > 1]]
```

and I get the plots number $1$ and $2$ which in the latter plot, the domain has been diminished.

[image]

**Question**

> I want to calculate the precise value of the solution of $g(x,y)=0$ at $y=\pi$. I use `NSolve` and `FindRoot`; both give the value $1.54545$ which is not correct according to the plot $2$, it should be around $x=1.571$. How can I obtain this value exactly?

```
y := Pi; NSolve[g[x, y] == 0  && 1.5 < x < 1.6 , x] 
FindRoot[g[x, y] == 0  , {x, 1.57}]

(*{{x -> 1.54545}}*)
```

Comment: In the plot you restricted the solutions to the region `f[x, y] > 1` you did not use the same restriction in `NSolve` or `FindRoot`. You must be consistent.

Comment: @BobHanlon Does it affect? Since I am investigating the plots result in which the condition has already been considered.

Comment: @BobHanlon I want to know the value of the given curve at $y=\pi$.

Comment: Which curve, i.e., with or without the constraint that `f[x, y] > 1`? If you require that `f[x, y] > 1` then as shown in your plots, the curve does not extend to `y == Pi`. Only if you remove the constraint does the curve extend to `y == Pi` and then you get the solution provided by your use of `NSolve` or `FindRoot` (which did not include the constraint `f[x, y] > 1`). Evaluation of `With[{y = Pi}, 
 NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 15/10 < x < 16/10 && f[x, y] > 1, x]]` indicates that there is no solution with the given constraints.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you very much. Your last sentence is my answer; there is no solution for the equation (in the mentioned domain) assuming that constraint. If you let me, I ask my final question: is it possible to calculate the maximum value of $x$ that my curve tends to that? I mean the maximum value of $1.5<x<1.6$ assuming the condition $f(x, y )>1$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Maximize[{D[g[x, π], x], 1.5 < x < 1.6}, x]
Minimize[{D[g[x, π], x], 1.5 < x < 1.6}, x]
```

> `{-5.00535, {x -> 1.5}}`
> `{-10.1372, {x -> 1.6}}`

It means that `g[x, π]` is a decreasing function.

```
Minimize[{g[x, π], 1.5 < x < 1.6}, x]
Maximize[{g[x, π], 1.5 < x < 1.6}, x]
```

> `{-0.41069, {x -> 1.6}}`
> `{0.250249, {x -> 1.5}}`

All this indicated that `g[x, π]` have exact one root in the interval `1.5<x<1.6`.

Comment: Thanks. Then, the curve I have plotted does not have any solution at $y=\pi$. @cvgmt

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment, rather than the answer, but I use this field to be able to show a plot.
As Bob Hanlon already mentioned, without the restriction (that you did not use during the solution of the equation `g(x,y)=0`) one gets:

```
g[x_, y_] := (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) + 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

    Show[{
  ContourPlot[{y == \[Pi], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.5, 
    1.6}, {y, \[Pi] - 0.1, Pi + 0.1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
   PlotPoints -> 10],
  Graphics[{Dashed, Black, 
    Line[{{1.54545, \[Pi] - 0.1}, {1.54545, \[Pi] + 0.1}}]}]
  }]
```

which yields the following plot:

[image]

The horizontal blue line shows the level `y=Pi` while the dashed black vertical line indicates `x=1.54545`.

I conclude that everything is correct with your solution of the equation.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. my question was about the second curve (the right curve in your plot); so, does this mean that the right curve does not cross this blue line? that is there is no root for this curve at $y=\pi$ ?@Alexei Boulbitch

Comment: @math2021 Yes, it does.