# How to calculate the maximum value of $x $ which satisfy the conditions $g(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y)>1$?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy, maximum

I have two functions $ f(x,y) $ and $ g(x,y) $ over the domains $ 1<x< 2$ and  $0<y<\pi$. I use `ContourPlot` to ses those values of $(x,y)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$ assuming that $f(x,y)>1$

```
f[x_, y_] :=  Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];
g[x_, y_] := (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

ContourPlot[  g[x, y] == 0 , {x, 1,2}, {y, 0, Pi}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},   f[x, y] > 1]]
```

I get this plot

[image]

**Question**

> Using `With[{y = Pi},   NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 15/10 < x < 16/10 && f[x, y] > 1, x]]`
> and as can be seen in the plot, we know that there is no solution at $y=\pi$. Is it possible to calculate the MAXIMUM value of $1 < x < 2$ which the blue curve tends to? In other word, is it possible to calculate the MAXIMUM value of $1 < x < 2$ which satisfy the conditions $g(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y)>1$ over the mentioned domain of $0<y<\pi$?

Numerically, using `With[ { y = 3.123} , NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 1.5 < x < 1.6 && f[x, y] > 1, x] ] (* x->1.57076 *)`, there might be around $x\approx 1.57076$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NMaximize[{x, g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] > 1, 1 < x < 2, 
  0 < y < π}, {x, y}]
```

> `{1.56332, {x -> 1.56332, y -> 2.85669}}`

```
NMaximize[{x, g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] > 1, 156/100 < x < 160/100, 
  3 < y < π}, {x, y}]
```

> `{1.57079, {x -> 1.57079, y -> 3.13717}}`

Comment: Thanks. But when we increase the ContourPlot precision (the picture is attached in my  previous question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263805/nsolve-and-findroot-give-a-value-which-is-not-correct-how-can-i-obtain-the-exac?noredirect=1#comment657303_263805), it seems that it should be around $1.571$. @cvgmt

Comment: This code ` With[ { y = 3.123} , NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 1.5 < x < 1.6 && f[x, y] > 1, x] ]   (* x->1.57076 *) ` , gives $(x,y)=(1.57076,3.123)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, so, the accuracy of the result depends on the domain.

Comment: @math2021 - Machine precision calculations are not exact. They neither track nor control precision. The results can be good, mediocre, or bad depending on the specific calculations involved. For better results (but slower) use arbitrary-precision by specifying a `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: Trying different precision values gives different results, sometimes with an error. @BobHanlon

Comment: @math2021 - without seeing what you tried I cannot say what is occurring. I recommend that you post a new question showing what you tried and explain what problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Since g[x,y] only depends on Cos[y], Solve for Cos[y] and insert into f[x,ArcCos[result]] for NMaximize.

```
f[x_, y_] = 
   Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] // 
TrigExpand
g[x_, y_] = (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) + 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
     x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2] // TrigExpand

(ccy = cy /. Solve[(g[x, y] /. Cos[y] -> cy) == 0, cy]) // TableForm

NMaximize[{x, f[x, ArcCos[ccy[[1]]]] > 1, 1 < x < 2}, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50]/Pi

(*   {0.49999999999999999999999985324310177745750765974840, {(
      x -> 1.5707963267948966192313212305893581225341055138385)/\[Pi]}}   *)
```

Comment: Running your code, I get ` {0.63661977236758134307553505349005744813783858296183, {(
  x -> 2.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)/\[Pi]}} `  @Akku 14

Comment: Then try  `ArcCos[ccy[[2]]] ` or choose other starting values. `Plot[f[x, ArcCos[ccy[[1]]]], {x, 1, 2}] ` and `Plot[f[x, ArcCos[ccy[[2]]]], {x, 1, 2}] `  to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. Then, you should edit your answer since the result is different. @ Akku14

Comment: On my version 8.0 result is as i showed.

Comment: OK, I use version 12 which gives the other result in my first comment.